# Is there a LabelLayout in HTML / SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, label

I need something similar to [this Android library](https://github.com/luxiliu/LabelLayout) in HTML / SCSS.
Some SCSS code would be enough too, so it **don't need to be a library**!

I would use the Label at the bottom right inside a parent div.
**It needs to fit in the container**, so not going above the div underneath or the div next to it on the right side
*I hope you can help me and thank you in advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this might help you.

```html
<div class="item" data-box-label="My label"></div>
```

```css
.item {
     width: 300px;
     height: 150px;
     background-color: black;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
}
.item::after {
      width: 150px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: green;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 30px;
      color: white;
      content: attr(data-box-label);
      bottom: 13%;
      right: -13%;
      position: absolute;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

The main div needs to have `overflow: hidden` (so it does not overlap) and `position: relative` so the `::after` element with `position: absolute` is inside it. You might want to change the `height` and `width` of the label box (the ::after element), but don't forget to change the `right` and `bottom` properties, because it will change its position when you change it's size.

There is also preview on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/silencesys/pen/qGBRvw).

### EDIT

**Updated Version works perfectly**
(have a look in comments)

Comment: It works for this specific height and width, but my layout is responsive so the width is 100% and then there are problemes with the right positioning. So e.g. on PC the right attribute needs to be -8.5% and on a 440x920 Phone it would be something about -15%. **It helps a lot** but it would be even better if it is responsive

Comment: If you have fixed label width and height, you can try this pen https://codepen.io/silencesys/pen/gJOxxm, I have changed the translate property so the label is centered at the bottom-right corner. However, I'm not sure if it will work when label will have dynamic size.